Simplification of hypergeometric functions
I am trying to calculate the variance of the mean parameterised beta-binomial distribution. The probability mass function is given by
BB[y_, m_, u_, s_] := (
 Beta[u/s + y, m + (1 - u)/s - y] Binomial[m, y])/Beta[u/s, (1 - u)/s]

where $y=0,\cdots,m$ for $m=0,1,\cdots,$ $0<u<1$, and $\sigma>0$. I
I can calculate the variance as follow
Ex = FullSimplify[Sum[y*BB[y, m, u, s], {y, 0, m}]]
Ex2 = FullSimplify[Sum[y^2*BB[y, m, u, s], {y, 0, m}]]
var = FullSimplify[Ex2 - Ex^2]

This leads to the following answer
$$-\frac{m (u-1) u (m s+1)}{s+1}.$$
The following should provide the same answer, but I am having trouble simplifying the resulting expression to be the same as the answer above.
FullSimplify[Sum[(y - m*u)^2*BB[y, m, u, s], {y, 0, m}], 
 Assumptions -> 0 < u < 1 && s > 0 && m \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers]

Which results in:
$$\frac{\pi  m u \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right) \left(\frac{(m-1) (2 s+1) (s+u) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(2-m,\frac{u}{s}+2;\frac{-((m-2) s)+u-1}{s};1\right)}{(u-1) (m s+1)}+s (1-m u) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(-m,\frac{u}{s};\frac{-m s+s+u-1}{s};1\right)\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  (m s-u+1)}{s}\right)}{\Gamma \left(m+\frac{1}{s}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1-u}{s}\right)}$$
Can anyone advise on how to simplify this expression to match the variance I computed earlier?

One thing to try is to use \[Element] instead of \[Epsilon] in the assumptions.

Thanks, @MichaelE2! But it now returns ComplexInfinity and still not the same simplified answer. Do you have any other suggestions?

That usually means you should use the assumptions on the sum; but I just tried it, and Sum fails to find a closed form.

What you did initially requires knowing that the variance is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. (Not that that's any secret.)  What you can do is Expand the sum and then sum the parts separately which is what probably should be done for higher powers than 2 (i.e, for skewness, kurtosis, etc.).
BB[y_, m_, u_, s_] := (Beta[u/s + y, m + (1 - u)/s - y]  Binomial[m, y])/Beta[u/s, (1 - u)/s]
summand = List @@ ((y - m*u)^2*BB[y, m, u, s] // Expand);
sum = Sum[#, {y, 0, m}] & /@ summand // Total // FullSimplify

$$-\frac{m (u-1) u (m s+1)}{s+1}$$

+1 However, it is not necessary to convert to a List and then Total. You can Map a Sum  directly, e.g., sum = Sum[#, {y, 0, m}] & /@ ((y - m*u)^2*BB[y, m, u, s] // Expand) // Simplify

Another approach
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

BB[y_, m_, u_, 
  s_] := (Beta[u/s + y, m + (1 - u)/s - y] Binomial[m, y])/
  Beta[u/s, (1 - u)/s]

Generate a sequence for varying m
seq = Assuming[0 < u < 1 && s > 0,
  Sum[(y - #*u)^2*BB[y, #, u, s], {y, 0, #}] & /@
    Range[5] // FullSimplify]

(* {-((-1 + u) u), -((2 (1 + 2 s) (-1 + u) u)/(1 + s)), -((
  3 (1 + 3 s) (-1 + u) u)/(1 + s)), -((4 (1 + 4 s) (-1 + u) u)/(
  1 + s)), -((5 (1 + 5 s) (-1 + u) u)/(1 + s))} *)

Generalize from the sequence
FindSequenceFunction[seq, m] // Simplify

(* -((m (1 + m s) (-1 + u) u)/(1 + s)) *)

